# Package install via the Sitecore Installation Framework

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, packages

Is it possible to install Sitecore packages (including both items and files) via the Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) 2.0.0?

If this functionality is not available out-of-the-box in SIF, I assume given SIF's extensibility that it's possible to write such an extension. Does such an extension exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this task isn't available out-of-the box, it's absolutely possible. 
You can create an ASMX service responsible for installing Sitecore packages and a custom SIF module to consume the service.

Rob Ahnemann (creator of SIF-Less) has outlined how this can be achieved in this [blog post](http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/11/using-sif-to-install-sitecore-packages/).

Comment: This *should* definitely be added to SIF, any ideas where to plug this (except for the official support channel)?

Comment: BTW `Invoke-InstallModuleTask` is available in Commerce SIF (and that is what I use for the moment).